# Calculate $P(X_{16}=2|X_0=0)$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, markov-chains

Given a Markov Chain with three states 0,1,2 with the following State Transition Probabilites:

$$M = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0.3 & 0.3 & 0.4 \\
 0.2 & 0.7 & 0.1 \\
 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.5 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Calculate $P(X_{16}=2|X_0=0)$ and $P(X_{12}=2,X_{16}=2|X_0=0)$, without using brute force calculation.

$$P(X_{16}|X_0=0) = (M^{16})_{0,2}$$$M^n$ seems to converge to the following matrix starting from $n_0=16$:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0.222222 & 0.5 & 0.277778 \\
 0.222222 & 0.5 & 0.277778 \\
 0.222222 & 0.5 & 0.277778 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

How can I show this without using brute force calculation. Is there any trick to show that this converges to the given matrix from $n=16$ onwards?

For the second part of the question, I think $P(X_{12}=2,X_{16}=2|X_0=0)=P(X_{16}|X_{12})P(X_{12}|X_0=0)=(M^4)_{2,2}(M^{12}_{0,2}$, again is there a computational trick to obtain this elegantly?

Comment: Perhaps compute it by repeated squaring?  I.e., find $M^2$, $(M^2)^2=M^4$, $(M^4)^2=M^8$, and $(M^8)^2=M^{16}$ and by computing $M^{12}=M^8 M^4$.  (Is this still brute force calculation?)

Comment: What is the meaning of "starting from $n_0=16$" in "$M^n$ seems to converge to the following matrix starting from $n_0=16$"?